# H2 db - Opening example file in web console

Tags: h2

I am trying to open file I made from example code in a web console
code:
https://h2database.com/html/mvstore.html#example_code

running web console https://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#tutorial_starting_h2_console

error in the web console:
`Database "/correct/path/to/file" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-212] 90149/90149 (Help)`

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database " ...path... " not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-212]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:678)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.throwNotFound(Engine.java:189)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:72)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:222)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:201)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:338)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:122)
    at org.h2.util.JdbcUtils.getConnection(JdbcUtils.java:288)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebServer.getConnection(WebServer.java:808)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.login(WebApp.java:1033)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.process(WebApp.java:226)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.processRequest(WebApp.java:176)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:153)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:102)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

The file does exist and I can read it via Java code, but not with web console.

Comment: How exactly file name was specified in JDBC URL? It must be specified **without** `.mv.db` extension.

Comment: The code (java) tutorial does not mention any extensions, also file on the disk doesn't have any. I noticed that there are `.mv.db` and `.h2.db` extensions. Which should be used in `MVStore.open(path)`?

Comment: Update: I added `.mb.db` to filename. The Console does open it, but it's nothing inside, even though I can print from java code. What did I miss?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you work with MVStore directly. You cannot open these files with H2 Console. H2 Console works only with databases. MVStore is not a database.

Comment: Thank you for replying. What is the difference between MVStore and database? Can I create H2 database in Java without SQL or open existing `.mv.db` file in Java without SQL?

Comment: MVStore is a simple storage with key-value maps. H2 Database is a full-featured relational database management system. You cannot work with it directly without basic knowledge of SQL, but there are different Java persistent technologies, such as various implementations of JPA (Hibernate ORM, EclipseLink, OpenJPA) and others, you can use them without SQL, but SQL can be needed anyway for some complex or performance-critical operations.

Comment: Thank you again for explaining. We are trying to edit/manage file saved from OpenSensorHub - V2, which is using H2 or it's MVstore. It looks like, we can't use H2 Console to edit entries in files produced by OpenSensorHub (H2 datastore).